# Trying to run my virtualbox pc gives me a error

Tags: virtualbox

I just got virtualbox and waited like 30 mins while my computer created a windows 10 vm. Now, I get this error when I try to open it:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Coleas Computer.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Comment: It says `VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.`. So go to the BIOS and enable that.

Comment: Where is the bios? @PerlDuck

Comment: Ok I got it @PerlDuck it says "no bootable medium found" I thought I already picked the os?